# angular2 service instancied 2 times

Tags: angular, service, instance

I have a component which use 2 services .

```
 export class UseComponent {    
     constructor(private _service1: Service1,
               private _service2: Service2){}
```

The second service needs a method existing in a first service. thus I inject also the fisrty service in second

```
export class Service2{

constructor(private _service1: Service1) {};

getLabel(): string{
   return this._service1.getLanguageLabel();
}
```

the provider for service is in a module

```
  @NgModule({
   imports: [.....],
   declarations: [.....],
   providers: [Service1, Service2]
  })
  export class UseModule { }
```

when the UseComponent uses the method getLabel , the service1 is instancied again (first instanciation when the component is initialised)

Why this second instanciation ? How to avoid it ?

Comment: have you set provider in UseComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in general: https://plnkr.co/edit/pWgQ5iVNVVGmHBZsv2SD?p=preview

Take care that these services aren't in any other `module`'s provider list.

```js
@Injectable()
export class Service1 {

  constructor() {
    addLog('created service 1');
  }

  public anyFunc() {
    return "huhu";
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service2 {

  constructor(private _srv1: Service1) {
    addLog('created service 2');
  }

  public anyFunc() {
    return this._srv1.anyFunc();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <p *ngFor="let log of logs | async">{{log}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  private logs = logs;

  constructor(private _srv2: Service2) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'

    addLog(this._srv2.anyFunc());
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  providers: [Service1, Service2],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```